# Anchor is not working in wordpress,

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-type

I'm creating a custom theme, then a custom type, and when I try to put a (read more) link to the post, the anchor is not working. This is my code:

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php  $temp_query = $wp_query;
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args=array(
                'caller_get_posts'=>1,
                'post_type' => 'enfant',
                'paged'=>$paged
            );
            $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

        ?>

        <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
        ?>

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header class="top-cont">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                <div class="entry-content">
    <!-- first one  -->             <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo $src[0];?>" /></a>

                    <?php
                        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'maladies', '', ', ','');
                        if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
                            $numTerm = 0;
                            echo "<h3>Maladie : </h3>";
                            echo "<p>";
                            foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                                $numTerm++;
                                if ($numTerm == 1){
                                    echo " ".$term->name;
                                }
                                else{
                                    echo ", ".$term->name;
                                }
                            }
                            echo "</p><br/>";
                        }
                    ?>
        <!-- second one  -->            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" >Lire plus ...</a>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                    <?php
                        wp_link_pages( array(
                            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'adelia' ),
                            'after'  => '</div>',
                        ) );
                    ?>

                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
                <div class="foot"></div>
                <!--<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'adelia' ), '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="edit-link">', '</span></footer>' ); ?>-->
            </article><!-- #post-## -->


            <?php
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                /*if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                    comments_template();*/
            ?>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

both line commented are not working.

Comment: Very difficult to determine without a link to see the actual code ( the live or dev site ) but most probably you have some JS conflict / error. check your console and report ..

Comment: i've checked, but didn't find something about links or something like that.

Comment: the error will not be "link" specific. but most likely jQUery or JS related. if a js error occurs prior to the link itself, it can break ( stop ) all the scripts that appear afterwards ..

Comment: i've just found some warning and one caroufredSel error which tells there is no elemet for #caroufredsel

Comment: I tried another thing, i created a filter hook which adds the read more button, but the same problem, it doesn't work, the link is not clickable, I need more help pleaaaaaaase

Comment: disable the carouselfred script loading on pages where it does not appear . also, and I can not stress it more - if you want "us" to pinpoint the problem you must supply a a link to a "live" site..

Answer (score 0):

it is difficult to find out bug:
i have try something for you, hope it will works.

```
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php  $temp_query = $wp_query;
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args=array(
            'caller_get_posts'=>1,
            'post_type' => 'enfant',
            'paged'=>$paged
        );
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

    ?>

    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        //$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
    ?>

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="top-cont">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
<!-- first one  -->             <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));?>" /></a>

                <?php
                    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'maladies', '', ', ','');
                    if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
                        $numTerm = 0;
                        echo "<h3>Maladie : </h3>";
                        echo "<p>";
                        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
                            $numTerm++;
                            if ($numTerm == 1){
                                echo " ".$term->name;
                            }
                            else{
                                echo ", ".$term->name;
                            }
                        }
                        echo "</p><br/>";
                    }
                ?>
    <!-- second one  -->            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" >Lire plus ...</a>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>

                <?php
                    wp_link_pages( array(
                        'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'adelia' ),
                        'after'  => '</div>',
                    ) );
                ?>

            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <div class="foot"></div>
            <!--<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'adelia' ), '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="edit-link">', '</span></footer>' ); ?>-->
        </article><!-- #post-## -->


        <?php
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
            /*if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                comments_template();*/
        ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping, for the first proposition, i checked the console for errors but i find other errors like box-sizing, but didn't find something concerning our case, and the second answer, i've done the modification but, the image is not displayed. tnx a lot, i'm waiting for more answers (if it's possible)!!!